# Possible to Customise Groups?

Tags: security, apex-managed-sharing

It it possible to:

1) Add new **Type** values for Groups? This is a picklist field.

2) Customise the **page layout** for Public Groups?

3) Create a **text field** for (Public) Groups?

The [Group object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/user_groups.htm) doesn't appear in the **Object Manager** (or in the **Setup** menu in SF Classic), and the **Type** field doesn't appear in the page layout for a Public Group, but it is visible from Workbench.

[image: Public Group Page Layout]

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like an [x-y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What problem (X) are you trying to solve with this solution (Y)?

Comment: Simply trying to set up a better way to organise Public Groups and add descriptions to them as we will be using Apex managed sharing extensively. Resorting to naming conventions for organising them is far from ideal, but it seems to be one of the only options. We are already seting up group hierarchies.

Comment: Yeah, we have a custom solution that uses public groups that way, it ended up being a naming-convention thing. The answer here is probably as good as it gets, for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Add new Type values for Groups? This is a picklist field.

Nope - the Type values are reserved for specific SFDC functionality such as `Case` (case queues), `Lead`, (Lead queues), `Queue` (other queues), etc

> Customise the page layout for Public Groups?

Nope - Because no custom fields are allowed, no reason to customize layout

> Create a text field for (Public) Groups?

Nope - Simply not supported at this time. There is a [recent Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000015ADSQA2) for this

**Plausible Workaround**

What you might consider are Group naming conventions to help organize the groups.

Comment: Nope x 3, disappointing to hear, but thanks for your help.